# Coldfusion automatically save data

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, cfml, cfajaxproxy

Instead of the traditional Posting of forms (with a save button) to save data to a database using coldfusion.
Is there a sensible way of having information saved as the user exits the field.
Is this even good practice?

Comment: I think it's an exceptionally bad practice because the user is not explicitly doing something to say, "yes, this is what I want to submit.".

Comment: Unless, of course, you make it clear that data is being saved when the user exits the field. That being said, saving fields like that leads down a path that you probably don't want to travel. You might consider a save button next to each input. There are distinct advantages to that.

Comment: Youtube seems to do that as videos are updated.

Comment: What if someone abandons the form without completing it? Then you have incomplete data polluting your db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is via JavaScript, assign a `change` event to every field, then define that the event will make an Ajax call to save the data in that particular field. You should need a single target URL that takes some primary key and the field name in question.

What you really need to consider though, is the bandwidth required to support such a process. What is your current load? Concurrent users? Concurrent form usage?

If you have 100 people filling out a 10 field form, you currently have 100 `HTTP POST` requests to deal with. Can you handle 1000 `HTTP POST` calls if every field saves on its own? What about 1000 people at a time? 10k? 100k? And larger forms, how many of those do you have?

The functionality is fairly trivial to implement, what is not trivial is the potential impact on your infrastructure.